# Connecting C2960s To router

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, router, cisco-ios

thanks for reading.
So I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to real network engineering. I've started my ICND1 and we've long talked about connecting routers and switches etc etc etc... I understand all the protocols and how they work, but can you connect a decent layer 2 switch like the c2960s to a home router and have that work?
I googled quite a bit and everyone kept showing examples of "Quick fix" solutions that involved super easy Layer 2 to Layer 3 on simple Linksys home products.
I'm trying to learn how to interconnect a router to my switch and this is purely for learning purposes with the switch and IOS. I know how to do it already with ALL Cisco hardware, but is it possible with a simple E900 wireless router if someone were to need a simple lab on a budget?

Thank you for any feed back or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the switch, the router is a regular computer (be it Cisco or whatever brand). The router or the PC might well support 802.1Q trunking, though.

About the switch port:

- If you want to connect all VLANs on the 2960 through an 802.1Q trunk to the router, it will depend on whether the E900 supports that. If it does, you will need to configure it on both sides.
- If you just want to connect the 2960 with a single VLAN to the E900, just configure the port as an "access" port set to that VLAN.

About the physical connection:

- If your E900 has switch ports and you connect the switch to one, you *may* need to use a crossover cable (or you may not, it depends).
- If your E900 has only regular ports, you will use a regular cable.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to connect a 2960 (I'm assuming a default configuration) to your router.  The IP address of the LAN interface of your router is the default gateway for all devices plugged into the switch.